# Random Freezing Windows 7...Readyboost?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, readyboost

After I leave my computer idle for about 15 minutes and come back, everything just doesn't respond. It takes 1 minute to close the browser and when loading a webpage it responds with "page does not respond". Opening task manager is also a lengthy process. However, it is not an issue with cpu power or a runaway process because the cpu was only being used around 10%. Memory usage was 40% and the disk still had some space and the hard drive indicator light was not freaking out (so no page filing issues).

The only way I got out of this situation was by unplugging the flash drive I use for readyboost from the back of my computer. Everything became immediately fast and back to normal (after a cpu jump to about 50% for about 10 sec (im assuming windows had to do something about losing the readyboost drive and realizing that the cache drive would be the main one))

Could the problem have to do with readyboost or something else and why is this happening?

Edit: Upon inserting the drive the computer immediately begins not to respond when opening new windows. Could this be a corrupt flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without some testing.  I find it hard to believe its ReadyBoost thats causing the issue.  My gut feeling is that there is something wrong with the drive, or the USB controller.

One of the advantages of ReadyBoost is that it uses the SuperFetch to predict what file you are going to read next and write it to the ReadyBoost cache.  If the cache is busy or the file is not in the cache, the system reads the file from the drive normally.  ReadyBoost can only help your system, even if the increase in performance is so minimal you wouldnt see it.

I would scan the disk for errors using Scandisk.  I bet you will find bad sectors.